# Add a decimal to calculator app swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need help where to add the decimal function in the following code?  I found the same question that had the same code but the corrections did not work.  Looking for any help here!

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if performingMath == true {
        label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
        performingMath = false
    }
    else {
        label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
    }
}

@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16{
        previousNumber = Double(label.text!)!

    if sender.tag == 12 { //Divide
        label.text = "/";
    }
}
```

There is more code below with the other func buttons (multiply, add, subtract, etc...)

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What do you mean by decimal function? Do you need a keyboard with a decimal point?

Comment: Yes a keyboard with a decimal point!

Comment: You would normally need a `textField` to enter the numbers. You can choose the type of keyboard for a `textField` in Interface Builder properties. In your case you would need the decimal keyboard

Comment: The code above is for a calculator app on the screen so a keyboard is not used.  The IBAction func numbers is for the numbers buttons and the IBAction func buttons is for the basic operation for arithmetic.  The results go to the IBoutlet weak var label.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another button for the decimal point. You would need to check that pressing a decimal point made sense. For example:

```
if label.text == "" {
    // Decimal at the start means add a zero
    label.text = "0."
} else if label.text.contains(".") {
    // Don’t add another decimal point!
}

// To get number from label
if let number = Double(label.text) {
    // Use the number here
}
```